# Changing the background image of a circle

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-image

I am trying to draw a number of CSS generated circles that have images as background. In my current code, the background image is set as a fixed image in the CSS code.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.circle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("http://deepchains.com/images/team.png") center / cover no-repeat;
  opacity: .25;
  transition: .25s;
}

.circle:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  color: transparent;
}

.circle:hover {
  color: transparent;
}

.ccont {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.ccont:hover {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="circle" href="http://www.url1.html">
    <div class="ccont" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration:none !important;">This is <br>Text1</div>
  </a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://www.url2.html">
    <div class="ccont" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration:none !important;">This is <br>Text2</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is a sample result that I see in Chrome Browser:

[image]

My question is how to change the background images of each circle separately in the HTML code? I will have a number of these circles that I like them to be aligned and in the same line, and I want to set their background images in the HTML code and remove the background image from the CSS. How can I do that?

Comment: how to remove from css: select the line in css and press delete. then add the image in the html output. I would recommend using flexbox to align text + images.

Comment: Why remove them from CSS? Unless you want to have them have constant background images, you can use inline styles.

Comment: @lolbas can you please show the code? I want each of them to have a different background image.

Comment: @TJ1 take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp). Basically, you can write CSS as-is into `style` attribute of HTML tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution is to transform your peudo element to an element and use background-image as inline style so you can easily change the image for each element and apply all the same properties as the pseudo element:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.circle .image {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  opacity: .25;
  transition: .25s;
}

.circle:hover .image {
  opacity: 1;
  color: transparent;
}

.circle:hover .ccont{
  color: transparent;
}

.ccont {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="circle" href="http://www.url1.html">
   <span class="image" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300/)"></span> 
    <div class="ccont" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration:none !important;">This is <br>Text1</div>
  </a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://www.url2.html">
  <span class="image" style="background-image:url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/)"></span>
    <div class="ccont" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration:none !important;">This is <br>Text2</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: that is a great answer. One minor question: I am running this on Chrome. When I used your modification, the text "This is Text1" only disappears when my mouse is on top of the text. I want it to disappear when it is on top of the circle. Can you please help with that?

Comment: @TJ1 am also on chrome .. are you sure you took all the modification, all the CSS/HTML ? and you saw this in the snippet here or in your site ?

Comment: Yes I copied all of your modifications, CSS and HTML.  The snippet here acts as expected, meaning if the mouse is on any part of the circle the text disappears. But on my site text only disappears if the mouse is on the text.

Comment: @TJ1 can you show me the site then ? maybe another CSS in conflict

Comment: Actually, it is running on my local computer, it is not uploaded to the internet.

Comment: try to add this also `.circle:hover .ccont {
  color: transparent;
}`

Comment: Great it worked. Can you please explain what it does?

Answer (score 2):

Simply set up the background image on the pseudo to be inherited from parent, set the size on parent to 0 to hide it there, and finally, set `style="background-image: url(...)"` in the markup.

*Updated*

You can even drop the inner `div` and still achieve the same effect

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  background-size: 0;              /*  hide image by set its size to 0  */
}

.circle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: inherit;       /*  inherit from parent  */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: .25;
  transition: .25s;
}

.circle:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.circle:hover {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="circle" href="http://www.url1.html" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=1070);">
    This is <br>Text1
  </a>
  <a class="circle" href="http://www.url2.html"  style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/300?image=1072);">
    This is <br>Text2
  </a>
</div>
```